# Pandas Covid-data homework

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a function that returns the requested daily and aggregate data for the requested country from the current daily COVID-19 epidemic data.

Source: http://raw.githubusercontent.com/ec-jrc/COVID-19/master/data-of-world/jrc-covid-19-all-days-of-world.csv

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("http://raw.githubusercontent.com/ec-jrc/COVID-19/master/data-of-world/jrc-covid-19-all-days-of-world.csv")
```

I need to create the following function:

```
def get_covid_data(country, datafield = "Deceased"):
  """Returns the selected data for the specified country.
```

Parameters:

- country (str) - the name of the selected country, example: 'Hungary'
- datafield (str) - one of 'Deceased' (default), 'Positive' or 'Recovered'

Returns:

- number of all cases to date, and the number of new cases on the last day

Example usage:

```
> get_covid_data('Hungary', 'Recovered')
> (796435,607)
```

returns cumulative, last_day

Update:

Thanks for the advice! I've tried to use the following code:

```
def get_covid_data(country, datafield = "Deceased"):  
  country_data = dataset.loc[dataset.CountryName == country, 'CumulativeDeceased']
  cumulative = country_data.max()
  difference = country_data.diff()
  last_day = difference.iloc[-1:].values[0]
  return cumulative, last_day

def get_covid_data(country, datafield = "Positive"): 
  country_data = dataset.loc[dataset.CountryName == country, 'CumulativePositive']
  cumulative = country_data.max()
  difference = country_data.diff()
  last_day = difference.iloc[-1:].values[0]
  return cumulative, last_day

def get_covid_data(country, datafield = "Recovered"): 
  country_data = dataset.loc[dataset.CountryName == country, 'CumulativeRecovered']
  cumulative = country_data.max()
  difference = country_data.diff()
  last_day = difference.iloc[-1:].values[0]
  return cumulative, last_day  

get_covid_data("Italy","Positive")
```

My problem is, that this way I can only get the "Recovered" data even if I write "Positive" or "Deceased" in the function.

Comment: are you asking us to write the function for you? if so, i don't think you're going to get much learning out of this exercise

Comment: At least he/she is honest and put homework in the title.  Most people don't :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def get_covid_data(country):
    df = dataset[['CountryName','CumulativeDeceased']]
    
    df = df[df['CountryName']=='{}'.format(country)]
    return df
```

which gives for Ukraine:

```
get_covid_data('Ukraine')
  CountryName  CumulativeDeceased
1536       Ukraine                 0.0
2446       Ukraine                 0.0
2875       Ukraine                 0.0
3036       Ukraine                 0.0
3206       Ukraine                 0.0
...            ...                 ...
115057     Ukraine             64202.0
115229     Ukraine             64936.0
115406     Ukraine             65628.0
115579     Ukraine             66204.0
115601     Ukraine             66852.0

[544 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: You should read the documentation for pandas and learn from doing.